# Как получить правильный маршрут?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Я получаю координаты  из базы данных и рисую путь, точка которого отмечена красным, получается не точным и карта автоматически изменяет путь, переворачивает обратно. Координаты в базе данных получаются от gps. Как исправить, чтобы карта не поменял путь, а продолжал по  курсу заданным gps?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно передавать правильные координаты. Маршрут строится строго по тем координатам которые вы передаёте.

Comment: Но gps не даёт правилни маршрут

Comment: задача не до конца ясна. В базе хранятся координаты всех точек которые нужно проехать или какие?

Comment: В базе хранятся данные которые дал gps (lat, long, course and speed) но gps не всегда даёт правильние координаты

Comment: не думаю что задачу можно решить если координаты неточные(